# How to let python detect when a certain file is being saved/closed?

Tags: python, subprocess, detect, python-webbrowser, pytube

I made this program that lets the user input what they want to download. It then opens up a browser and YouTube with the keywords the user input. The user can copy and pastes as many URLs to the text file `url.txt`. Simply save the text file, press enter in the python shell, and the downloading starts. Is there a way for python to detect a certain file being closed or saved so that I won't have to press enter for the downloading to start?

```
import webbrowser
import pytube
from subprocess import call

key = input('Input what you want to download: ')
a_website = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+key
webbrowser.open_new(a_website)

open('url.txt', 'w')
call(['notepad', 'url.txt'])

start = input('Press enter when ready to download >>> ')
with open('url.txt','r') as f:
    urls = f.readlines()
number = len(urls)
num = 0
for url in urls:
    num += 1
    print('Downloading video',num,'of',number)
    yt = pytube.YouTube(url)
    stream = yt.streams.first()
    stream.download()

open('url.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: Have a look at the [watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) library!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of watchdog detection:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```